# How to update google services plugin?

Tags: android

Trying to run app the following error occurs:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the 
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available 
>   at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-
>   services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.2.0.

I changed different versions but it didn't work again

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mher.loginregister"
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
 core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

2)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
} 

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same version of all the Firebase **and Google** dependencies.

Use this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
```

Note the difference in the version number for `firebase-database`.

Comment: Thanks alot! Hovering over the compile lines popped up a tooltip indicating the most recent versions for all my firebase dependencies. I'm surprised they don't have a GUI option to update those or at least notify the user that there is an update.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your build.gradle should look like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mher.loginregister"
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
 core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```